# regular expression to split string avoiding double tokens

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

In order to split a string value into an array using javascript I need to split using delimiters. Repeated delimiters indicate a sub-value within the array, so for example

> abc+!+;def+!+!+;123+!+;xyz

should split into abc, [def, 123], xyz

My nearest expression is ((?:+!(?!+!))+\;|$) but thinking about it that may be the one I first started with, as I've gone through so many many variations since then.

There is probably a blindingly obvious answer, but after what seems an eternity I'm now stumped. I took a look at [regex to parse string with escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208694/regex-to-parse-string-with-escaped-characters?rq=1), and similar articles which were close although not the same problem, but basically came to a stop with ideas.

Somewhere out there someone will know regular expressions far better than I do, and hope that they have an answer

Comment: You're going to have to explain the basic syntax of your original string. What are the rules for those delimiters? If you were starting out with the data structure you want to end up with (the array with sub-arrays), what is the process you'd follow to generate the string?

Comment: I agree.  For example do those numbers in the second grouping...will those always be numbers or letters and numbers. I guess that goes for all these subsets..What is the bigger pattern here. Maybe you can throw up a few example strings?

Comment: The string is from an external source, so can't change the syntax. Basically +! and +; is a terminating symbol. +!+; is at one level. Within the whole phrase, further levels are prefixed by another +! so +!+!+; is a sub-level within that phrase, +!+!+!+; is a sub-sub-level and so on.

Comment: `+` is a special char so it must be preceded by a backslash; `;` is not a special char so it does not require backslash: `((?:\+!(?!\+!))\+;|$)`
Oh by the way why you wrote that pipe `|`?

Comment: The values will be alpha-numeric and possibly symbols too - it's user input, so no guarantee that punctuation characters etc may also be in there.

Comment: @burn about the pipe - grasping at straws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by using `.split()` with this [basic pattern](http://regex101.com/r/hX5cG3):

```
\b\+!\+;\b
```

And then:

```
\b\+!\+!\+;\b
```

And so on, and so forth.  You will need to turn this into a recursive function, but I made a basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6yW/2/) to get you started.  First we split the string using our first expression.  Then we create our newer expression by adding `!\+` (this can easily be done dynamically).  Now we can loop through our initial array, see if the string matches our new expression and if it does split it again.

```
var string = 'abc+!+;def+!+!+;123+!+;xyz',
    data = string.split(/\b\+!\+;\b/);

var regex = /\b\+!\+!\+;\b/
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var string = data[i];

    if(string.match(regex)) {
        data[i] = string.split(regex);
    }
}

console.log(data);
// ["abc", ["def", "123"], "xyz"]
```

I'm leaving the task of making this a recursive function up to OP.  If you want some direction, I can try to provide some more insight.